# Regex match after last / and first underscore

Tags: r, regex, stringr

Assuming I have the following string:

```
string = "path/stack/over_flow/Pedro_account"
```

I am intrested in matching the first 2 characters after the last / and before the first _. So in this case the desired out put is:

```
Pe
```

What I have so far is a mix of substr and str_extract:

```
substr(str_extract(string, "[^/]*$"),1,2)
```

which of course will give an answer but I belive there is a nice regex for it as well, and that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(stringr)
str_extract(string, "(?<=/)[^/]{2}(?=[^/]*$)")
## => [1] "Pe"
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/WxknOj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sGPI3j/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=/)` - a location immediately preceded with a `/` char
- `[^/]{2}` - two chars other than `/`
- `(?=[^/]*$)` - a location immediately preceded with zero or more chars other than `/` till the end of string.

Answer (score 2):

Using *basename* to get the last folder name, then *substring*:

```
substr(basename("path/stack/over_flow/Pedro_account"), 1, 2)
# [1] "Pe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove everything till last `/` and extract first 2 characters.

Base R -

```
string = "path/stack/over_flow/Pedro_account"
substr(sub('.*/', '', string), 1, 2)
#[1] "Pe"
```

`stringr`

```
substr(stringr::str_remove(string, '.*/'), 1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use str_match with a capture group:

- `/` Match literally
- `([^/_]{2})` Capture 2 chars other than `/` or `_` in **group 1**
- `[^/]*` Match optional chars other than `/`
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VB8dOP/1) and a [R demo](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyczqSixqFKjuKQoMy@9SJMLwlCwVVAqSCzJ0C8uSUzO1s8vSy2KT8vJL9cPSE0pyo9PTE7OL80rUQKpjs9NLEnOgBqgo6CkrxEdpx8fW21UqwlkxGqpKGlG6xjF/v8PAA).

Example

```
library(stringr)
string = "path/stack/over_flow/Pedro_account"
str_match(string, "/([^/_]{2})[^/]*$")[,2]
```

Output

```
[1] "Pe"
```